# Why can I call a function on a Class that has not been instantiated?

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain why the below code is able to call the SayHello function and print out "Hello".

The constructor and destructor never get called as there is no object actually created, so why then can I call the SayHello function??

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout<<"In Constructor"<<std::endl;
    };
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"In Destructor"<<std::endl;
    };

    void SayHello()
    {
        std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    A* a = nullptr;
    a->SayHello();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm certain this has been asked like this before.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behaviour. It happens to work because `SayHello` doesn't access any member data. Don't do this.

Comment: Yes I know not to do it, I just want to know why it happens

Comment: @HarryBoy: Because undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything can happen; anything includes the function working as it would if called properly.

Comment: when you say it's an undefined behaviour, could you quote where this knowledge come from ?

Comment: @Guiroux have a look at the question I marked this as a duplicate of, it has the necessary references.

Comment: thank you ofr the precision